# Порядок оформления перевода

Tags: пунктуация

Как оформить перевод слов в кавычках в следующих предложениях?

1. До обеда начальник обучал меня языку; вплетая слова в жесты, он объяснил, что я теперь такой же, как все, и что скоро покину этот зал, чтобы увидеть «райхан» — королеву, пожалуй, именно таким словом описывался человек, по заверению мальчишки, носящий корону.
2. ...а такой «хутур» — иноземец(,) — как я, если постарается, навестит госпожу не один раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что такое " хутур" ? Указанная запятая нужна.

Comment: Произношение выдуманного иностранного слова.

Comment: Нет, заключать в кавычки не нужно.

Comment: А здесь?  
Я уточнил, владеет ли государыня этим домом и ещё землёй вокруг, и получил скорый ответ: «арх лур!» — «много земли!».

Comment: Здесь кавычки нужны, поскольку "арх лур! — много"  является ответом на вопрос , который вы задали собеседнику.